# What implementation of WebApp is the best if i just have one user who consuments it?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

The last time i wrote a WebApi it was a solution with multiple Accounts and Users. I used EF and MSSQL with JWT Tokens.
Now i have another situtation. I have a WebApi what will be called from another program, and just this one. To use EF and Database, feels me overkilled.
Is there any possibility to set just one acoount/user (maybe hardcoded) to use the API?

I googled around, sadly nothing found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a user, but an API authentication/authorization method, for example :

### 1. Using API-Key

The client can send an API key in the headers of the request that you check from server-side. This can either be hard-coded in the server, or do a DB lookup for the key in a simple schema.
Using the DB you can have more context about the owner of the key and add/remove them dynamically.
[Here is a sample](https://github.com/Phoesion/Glow-Samples/tree/master/11_Authorization_ApiKey) (it uses the [Phoesion Glow](https://glow.phoesion.com) framework but it's the same with asp.net)
and [this is the auth middleware part](https://github.com/Phoesion/Glow-Samples/blob/master/11_Authorization_ApiKey/Services/Foompany.Services.SampleService1/ServiceMain.cs#L26)

### 2. Using JWT

You don't need users/identity-server etc to use JTW, you can generate a token using symmetric encryption with all the claims you want your token to contain.
*(with a little more work you can also use asymetric encryption to sign the tokens and give them to other api consumers)* 
[Here is a sample using this method](https://github.com/Phoesion/Glow-Samples/tree/master/11_Authorization_JWT_CustomAuthority)

### 3. Using HMAC

You can use encryption and hashing to verify that the request coming from the client are valid. In this method you hash the contents and sign them with a key, then send the signature in the headers of the request 
[More about HMAC here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) and [here (azure-specific)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/tutorials/hmac-header-tutorial?pivots=programming-language-csharp)

*( Disclaimer : The samples i mention above are written by me, because i am a developer of [Phoesion Glow](https://glow.phoesion.com) )*